# Remove a subquery and want a single query

Tags: mysql, join

```
select
  a1.`active_id`  
from
  active_table a1  
where
  a1.`active_id`  NOT IN (
    select
      a2.`active_id` 
    from
      view a2 
    group by
      a2.active_id 
      AND datediff(now(),
      active_date)
  )>'9'
```

Above query works well in MySql, but i want to remove subquery and want this as a single query.

Is there any other way to workout this? I think it might be possible with JOIN, but i don't know how.

Any help from your side most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have typo datediff() and >'9'

Can you try this?

```
SELECT a1.`active_id`  
FROM active_table a1 LEFT JOIN `view` a2 USING(active_id)
WHERE a2.`active_id` IS NULL
  AND datediff(now(), active_date) > 9
```